# "Body must be at least <x> characters" pops up even when I'm not trying to post

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, posting

This message:

[image: Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 11]

Comes up every time the answer textbox that has text in it loses focus.

The textbox losing focus should **never** result in this error message unless you press "post your answer".

This is even more annoying when trying to use formatting tools since you **have to** give the focus to these buttons:

[image: formatting buttons]

I'd like to see it appear only when you try to post the answer and have less than 30 characters in the body.

Comment: It pops up pretty much as soon as the focus leaves the text box, you don't even need to click on the toolbar.

Comment: +1 obligatory for the free-hand circles.

Comment: @ryan was hopping someone point it out. There are rules here.!

Comment: It appears that this error box doesn't prevent you from answering.  When I tested this issue, focus wasn't hijacked (from wherever it was when the error was rendered).

Comment: @Ben that's not the problem, the issue here is just bad user experience, like a teacher shouting on a student before he had chance to do something wrong. IMO it should be feature request not a bug report but as a moderator changed it, I'm hesitating to change it back.

Comment: @BenCollins exactly what Sha said, in my answer below, I'm trying to do the right thing and format my code and the UX is yelling at me for doing it. Highly annoying.

Answer (score 23):

[image]

This is my favorite time when it pops up. When I want to start an answer on SO with a code-block so I hit the built in button for creating a code-block and..... get an error message.

I love SE but this is really, really annoying.

Comment: Wait, people actually use the toolbar?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Only for bug hunting :-)